# Hash/# not a comment

Tags: python, python-2.7, comments, string-literals

G'day All,

I've searched far and wide (although using # in a search doesn't help much...) but what I need to do is use # in a line but not have it commented. I'm building a .kml within Python 2.7 and wish to apply a style and to do so, require the a '#' but as soon as I type it, python treats the following text as a comment. My code is as follows;

```
f.write("   <styleUrl>#Range" + str(row[3]) + "</description>\n")
```

What do I need to do to be able to type/print #?

Comment: That should work... Have you tried using a different non-broken IDE? Or use `'` instead of `"`?

Comment: Are you sure Python treats '#' inside of string as comments? What's the error traceback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is not treating the following text as a comment. Your IDE might be mistakenly interpreting it as such and applying syntax highlighting incorrectly, but a `#` inside a quoted string is just a `#`, not the beginning of a comment.

Comment: Ah.... I see that it works when I run it - I just need to ignore the IDE - Thanks for your quick response.